# Frequency of arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, frequency

I'm trying to write a code which works like this:
*it first gets an int from the user which presents the number of array indexes the user would like to own (**n**), then the code creates an array with **n** number of indexes. It then has to print the **frequency** of every entered number.*
Running my below code results in a segmentation fault. Any solution will in advance be appreciated.

My code:

```
int main()
{
    int n, index;
    cin>>n;
    int ar[n];
    int freq[100]={0};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin>>ar[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        index=ar[i];
        freq[index]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {

        cout<<freq[i]<<' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** 1<=n<=100

Comment: `freq[100]` goes from 0 through 99, so if you have values of 100 you'll either need to expand the array or always subtract one.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I've also tried 101, it didn't help. I guess the problem isn't this

Comment: You'll want std::vector. You have int ar[n], but n is not constexpr. Some compilers support that, but it's not c++ Provide the input that leads to the error. You also may want to close main with a }

Comment: I get that this is an exercise, but for practical applications you can just us an `std::map<int, int>` to count occurrences.

Comment: @KennyOstrom can't I solve this without vector?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ah yes, but I'd still like to do this manually :)

Comment: Of course you can, but the way you're doing it is using a vendor extension. It's not going to be portable, and it's a good idea to avoid that practice, in general. I don't have your compiler, so I can't run your code.

Comment: @KennyOstrom ah, thanks :)

Comment: Your second `for` should go up to `n`, not 100.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError OMG! You solved my problem thank you so much! My bad

Comment: Note: since all you care about is the frequencies, there's no need for `ar`. In one loop, read a number into a local integer variable and update the frequency counter for that number. In the second loop print out the frequencies. Save you a bunch of work by eliminating a whole loop, a bunch of memory, and a potential stack overflow because of that unnecessary memory .

Comment: Your `int ar[n];` is using Variable Length Arrays which are not standard C++.  For dynamically allocated arrays prefer to use `std::vector` or use `new`.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you so much for your very kind and helpful guidance :)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, I already got told so much to use Vector instead... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
int main ()
{
  int n, input;
  while (n > 100 || n < 1)

    cin >> n;

  // indexes 0 - 99
  int freq[100] = { 0 };

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      cout << "number: ";
      cin >> input;
      if (input > 0 && input <= 100)
        freq[input - 1]++;
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if (freq[i] != 0)
         cout << i + 1 << "-->" << freq[i] << &endl;


  return 0;
}
```

try it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Syw8cIWaI)